# Intact male dog aggresion. Will neuter help?

Tags: dogs, aggression, desexing

I have a 11 months old intact male dog (mix of GSB and local dog). He used to be very sociable since I have taken him to the dog park from very early age (3 months old). He is very well behaved and playful at home, around people and children.

However, in the last 2 months he has gotten very aggressive towards other male dogs (both intact and neutered). He would likely to pick a fight or get hot tempered very quickly and switch from wagging tail to aggressively fighting.

Now I have to let him play at the dog park at a time when no male dog is around, and if any appears, we have to leave!

I have research that neutering a dog may lower his aggression, but my opinion, I don't really support neutering as I think it is unnatural (please don't hate me it just my opinion). However, if it the best option for him to have fun and "join with the dog society", then I would still do it.

Please help me with my situation. This is my first time owning a dog and I have tried as hard as possible to training aggressive management but it doesn't seems to work. I also have tried use muzzle on him but he still pick up fights, and he got injured even more seriously since he cannot defense himself. I am also a graduates and just started working and cannot afford dog training, it is very expensive in my country.

Please help me, I would be very thankful. 
Sorry for my bad English. I am not from English native speaking coutries.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If possible, consult an expert to judge the dog's behavior. There might be things you're missing or things you're doing wrong. Also this could be a temporary thing as your dog started trying to find it's place in the pack's hierarchy.

Neutering might help but it's no guarantee and by far no universal solution to everything. Just as with people your dog might not like certain individuals.

Also if you're unsure about this decision consider trying a hormone suppressant first. These are small injections that will basically neuter the dog for about six to nine months rather than permanently, so you can do a test run, see what/if/how the behavior changes and later on undo, repeat, or finalize your decision. (As Rebecca mentioned as a comment there might be a higher risk of cancer involved although I don't know whether that's a general thing or specific to some injections.)

Comment: thank u for replying, I have also heard about the finding it's place in the pack's hierarchy thing. Some people said that it would be gone after 2 years old, not sure if it's true. It feels like he always want to be the alpha of every dog that's why he always pick up the fight with others.

In my country there is no hormone suppression injection for dogs yet, only for human, so I don't know if I should wait to see his behavior after a few months or a year before deciding to neuter him?

Comment: @PhuongVu I'd say wait and see, especially when you can handle those situations. You could even try to tire your dog **before** going to the park, so it'll have less energy for shenanigans to begin with.

Comment: I will add those injections are very unethical in the vet community, high risks of cancer.

Comment: @RebeccaRVT Interesting, haven't heard of that.

Comment: Ya I think it's prevalent in third world countries, we had a few from India who wanted it done but no vet would do it.